# Running K-Means on Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, k-means, databricks

I have the three centroids as `(2,5)`, `(6,2)` and `(1,1)` and a bunch of coordinates. I am trying to run k-means on this data with a k value of 3 using pyspark. My approach is to create a function into which i will input the coordinates and, it will return the centroid from which it is the nearest. I have defined the function as below:

```
def dist(x):
  b = {'d1':distance.euclidean((2,5),x),'d2':distance.euclidean((6,2),x),'d3':distance.euclidean((1,1),x)}
  def get_key(val):
    for key, value in b.items():
      if val == value:
        return key
  print(get_key(min(b.values())))
```

A sample of my coordinates are as below.

```
[(3.023, 5.138),
 (3.075, 4.989),
 (2.321, 5.35),
 (3.328, 4.944),
 (1.625, 1.362),
 (1.987, 1.266),
 ...]
```

How do i proceed further from here? I have been stuck on this for quite some time and would really appreciate some help.

Comment: Would you consider using [Spark ML KMeans](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.clustering.KMeans)

Comment: Yes absolutely. How can I use that?